# twitter like facebook integration in my own website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to have facebook integration in my website. Like in twitter in our profile settings, we only connect to facebook once and everytime we tweet .. it's automatically posted to our Facebook wall. Wanted to know if this is possible via facebook opengraph api. A user signs in on my website ... and his different actions performed on my website gets posted on his wall without providing/checking authentication every time he signs in to my website and perform an action (like in twitter)!!

Would appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to post to walls, you need to create an App so that you can request permissions to post to a Facebook wall (go to [Facebook Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) to get started).

Once you have done this, you can use the App Dashboard to set up the permissions your App requires. Then, you can use the Javascript API to get your users logged in on your website, at which point the permissions may be granted. From there, you can continue to use the JS API to post to a wall.

Note: You will need to set up Objects and Actions in your App - see the [Facebook Open Graph guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) for more details.

Comment: I've already made a an app and object/action. But what i need to figure out is ... how can i make the user's account associate with his facebook account. I don't want to prompt user everytime to enter his facebook id/pass everytime he performs an action.

Comment: Firstly, initialize the Facebook API:
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)

Add a 'Sign In To Facebook' link to your page with 'FB.login()' in the onClick attribute, as per the SDK:
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

If the user is logged in already, this will not be required.


Then, post to the wall as so:
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)